# Save forecast data to csv

Tags: python, csv, google-colaboratory, facebook-prophet

Hello I have  this code.

```py
forecast = m.predict(future)
forecast[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']]
forecast.tail(365)
```

```py
    ds  trend   yhat_lower  yhat_upper  trend_lower trend_upper additive_terms  additive_terms_lower    additive_terms_upper    weekly  weekly_lower    weekly_upper    multiplicative_terms    multiplicative_terms_lower  multiplicative_terms_upper  yhat
307 2022-12-30 01:00:00 8744.804921 4151.683644 19973.732090    8744.804921 8744.804921 3425.715807 3425.715807 3425.715807 3425.715807 3425.715807 3425.715807 0.0 0.0 0.0 12170.520728
308 2022-12-30 02:00:00 8743.882714 3948.935733 20003.308794    8743.882714 8743.882714 3691.081394 3691.081394 3691.081394
```

So I want to download/export this forecast data as csv file.

```py
from google.colab import files
files.download() # ? what I need do here.
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
forecast.to_csv('forecast.csv')
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```py
forecast = m.predict(future)
forecast_data = forecast[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']]
#forecast.tail(365)
print (forecast_data)

forecast_data.to_csv('myCsv.csv')
f.close()
```